# ConfigureISDPRequest error during profile package installation into an ISD-P on an eUICC

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I'm assembling the SGP.22 GetBoundProfilePackage response that starts with the InitialiseSecureChannelRequest for which I'm getting a 90 00 success code. The subsequent ConfigureISDPRequest is returning an errorReason 8 which is an scp03t/BSP security error.

There are several steps for the scp03t (now relabelled as BSP in v3 of SGP.22) process and ConfigureISDPRequest requires encryption and MACing. The error code doesn't provide a way of identifying which step contains the error.

The first step is to generate the ShS shared secret using  previously generated (for InitialiseSecureChannelRequest) smdpOtsk private key and euiccOtpk public key. This ECDH procedure is defined in [NIST SP 800-56Ar3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar3.pdf) section 5.7.1.2:

1. Compute the point P = hdAQB.
2. If P = Ø, destroy all intermediate values used in the attempted computation of P, then
   output an error indicator, and exit this process without further processing.
3. Else, set z = xP, where xP is the x-coordinate of P, and convert z to Z, using the field-
   element-to-byte string conversion routine defined in Appendix C.2.

My Golang code, having referred to [this post](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/goecdh) though I note I don't think it needs hashing after - that appears to be a TLS thing:

```
calcedX, _ := euiccOtpk.Curve.ScalarMult(euiccOtpk.X, euiccOtpk.Y, smdpOtsk.D.Bytes())
```

What isn't clear to me here is part 3 in the NIST SP 800-56Ar3 steps - convert z to Z, using the field-element-to-byte string conversion routine defined in Appendix C.2.

I've used the following code for the Field-Element-to-Byte String Conversion specified in Appendix C.2 and my question is whether or not this is correct?

```
    fixedBytes := make([]byte, 32)
    calcedX.FillBytes(fixedBytes)
    return fixedBytes
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you are implementing ECDH on your own? Does the default [Golang impl](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdh) does not work for you? If you implement the low level stuff by yourself this project will be endless. Test cectors for ECDH might be taken from [wycheproof](https://github.com/google/wycheproof/blob/master/testvectors/ecdh_secp256r1_test.json).
2. Take a look into the [test specification for SGP.22](https://www.gsma.com/esim/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/SGP.23-v1.10.pdf), search for `ConfigureISDPRequest` and related commands. Starting with Annex A you will find constants and data used in the test commands. It does not define real test vectors, but still helps to test your code interactions.

Comment: 1. Thanks I agree the Golang impl should do it "For NIST curves, this performs ECDH as specified in SEC 1, Version 2.0, Section 3.3.1, and returns the x-coordinate encoded according to SEC 1, Version 2.0, Section 2.3.5.".  I see the SEC 1 spec is the same as in 800-56Ar3 and SEC 1 section 2.3.5 contains the Field-Element-to-Byte String Conversion.

2. I don't see actual test data in SGP.23. That would be useful! I'm using the test certificates and keys from SGP.26.

Comment: @chrismode51 Since your problem seems to be only the ECDH part just take any test vectors available, e.g. I have added a link to wycheproof above. SGP.26 might not help, since the EC keys at this step are ephemerals keys.

Comment: Will compare with wycheproof that's great. On SGP.26 I'm using a key from that for the previous InitialiseSecureChannelRequest as that requires a signature. The public key from a new ephemeral key pair is also sent through to the eUICC in the InitialiseSecureChannelRequest payload so that it can be used in the next set of steps needed for ConfigureISDPRequest, for which calculating the ECDH shared secret is the first step.

Comment: For ref this openssl command also provides a verification method: 

openssl pkeyutl -derive -inkey ./ecpriv.der -peerkey ec.pubder -out ecdhshared.bin